# write dynamic html with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Given [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pp6nv/), what is preventing the HTML from being rendered?

***JavaScript***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function loadDiv( divId ) {
        $('#' + divId).html('<table><tr><td class="editable" id="' + divId + '">Edit Me</td></tr></table>');
    }

    $('td.editable').click(function() {
        var cellId = $('td.editable').attr('id');
        alert(cellId);
    });

    loadDiv( div1 );
    loadDiv( div2 );
});
```

My intention is to change the clicked cell into an input field and later post from it, but I'm not sure why it's not rendering.

Comment: div1 and div2 two are variables... put quotes around them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add quotes around your div ids.

```
loadDiv( "div1" );
loadDiv( "div2" );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pp6nv/1/

Since the tables are added after the page loads, you'll have to use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

```
$('body').on("click", "td.editable", function() {
    var cellId = $(this).prop('id');
    alert(cellId);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pp6nv/3/

Comment: Sigh. Thanks for that. What must happen for it to be able to get caught by the `click` function?